# Configuring IPtables to behave as a router on the edge of a VPN

Tags: iptables, routing, firewall, vpn, nat

I'd like to configure IPtables on a single linux machine that enables packets to flow in and out of a VPN.

Here's a small scale network of 3 nodes:

1. v1 : A linux machine inside the VPN. VPN Subnet is 10.10.100.0/22
2. out1 : A linux machine outside the VPN. It has information of how many nodes exist inside the VPN and their VPN IP's, but itself is not on the VPN
3. r  : A linux machine that has iptables set up for the routing requirement. It is on the VPN and out1 can also send packets to it. Hence its on the edge. r therefore has eth0 that is on the same network as out1 and tun0 which is its vpn interface

I have managed to have r be the "next hop" for all packets leaving out1, with destination 10.10.100.0/22. So packets are coming into r. The following two iptables rules on r enabled me to have out1, communicate with v1 over netcat

```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tun0 -j MASQUERADE
   iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Maybe these rules are incorrect because why would I need the MASQUERADE function?

When v1 tries to ACK the packets from out1, they reach r and get dropped. I confirmed using tcpdump, that v1 sends packets destined to out1 and they hit r, but they never get to out1.

How do I close the loop? I dont need to do NAT, since out1 already knows the destination IP's, I simply would like r to move packets from its eth0 to tun0 and tun0 to eth0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it

```
#Forward connections coming in from eth0 to tun0
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

#Masquerade packets leaving tun0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

#Forward Stateful connections coming in from tun0 to eth0
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
             -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following examples the VPN device name is `tun0` (OpenVPN) and the VPN gateway is 172.21.23.172.

1. Install VPN on your Linux router (I'm using ipvanish w. openvpn)
2. Route traffic using iptables

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o [VPN dev] -j MASQUERADE
   ```

   example:

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
3. Configure routing tables (to ensure that all traffic is routed through the VPN)

   ```
   sudo ip route add default via [VPN ipv4 address] dev [VPN dev]
   ```

   example:

   ```
   sudo ip route add default via 172.21.23.172 dev tun0
   ```
4. Check that devices on the network are indeed routing thru the VPN by running these commands:

   Windows:`tracert 1.1.1.1` Linux:`traceroute 1.1.1.1`

You're done!